# What's the difference between ^([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}$ and ([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}?

Tags: c#, regex

If I use **`([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}`** to match the input.
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` would be matched as a valid input.

But, if I add **^** at the beginning and **$** at the end. The expression **`^([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}$`** would match `1,2,3,4,5` as I desired.

My question is: What's the difference between **`^([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}$`** and **`([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}`** ? You know, I only add **^** and **$**.

Could you explain why does the difference happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the syntax diagram for `^([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}$`

[image: ^([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}$]

This is the syntax diagram for `([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}`
[image: ([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}]

You can see the difference between the 2 regular expressions is the first regular expression forces to match from `Start` of the string to `End` of the string.

The diagrams are generated using [**Regexper**](http://www.regexper.com/).

Answer (score 3):

`^` means match the start of the string, `$` means match the end of the string. So it basically means your string must exactly match the pattern, compare:

`^foo$` with `foo` as your regex.

Try and match it against `food`. The first will not match, because we don't hit the end of the string after the `foo` part.

Answer (score 3):

`([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}` would match anywhere in the string, I.e.: 2,,2abcd,35,54,67,23,04foobar would match.

`^([1-9]{1,2},){4}[1-9]{1,2}$` would only match if the entire string matches.  I.e.: the example above would not match.

`^` matches the start of a string, `$` the end.